# Cannot access server via SSH in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, ssh, unix

When I try logging in via `ssh root@server.org` I am asked for my password, however when I enter it, it doesn't work. I can access the server by a different user then run `su root` and the password works fine.

I have logged into my account via root user several times in the past. I was having a problem and followed a guide where I changed `PermitRootLogin` to `without-password` in `sshd_config` and restarted it. This started the problem. When I changed `PermitRootLogin` back to `yes`, the problem persisted.

The following appears in my `/var/log/auth.log` when I tail it.

```
Jul 30 15:54:44 dev-pc sshd[18150]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 027a1dbb.bb.sky.com [{IP_ADDRESS}] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jul 30 15:54:49 dev-pc sshd[18150]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost={IP_ADDRESS}  user=root
Jul 30 15:54:51 dev-pc sshd[18150]: Failed password for root from {IP_ADDRESS} port 50363 ssh2
```

Any ideas on what is causing this issue?

Comment: `pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost={IP_ADDRESS}  user=root` - pam says no, you sure you're using the correct password?

Comment: I know it's strange but I've been using only one password this whole time and it hasn't changed. The same password also works when I'm logged in on another account and try a `su root`.

Comment: Nvm, it's fixed. I did a `service ssh restart`.